# Why is align-items css not working for older versions of Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser

I have created a html form where i set the `align-items:center` property which works on newer version but not working for older versions.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="zip-input-social input-social" >
                    <div class="zipInput-div">
                        <label for="zip">Zip:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="textinput formfield zipInput" maxlength="5" >
             </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
.input-social {
    padding: 7px 0;
}
.zip-input-social {
    display: block!important;
}
.input, .input-social {
    padding: 17px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.input-social .zipInput-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
label {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 35px;
    color: #2a2a2c;
}
```

what should i do that it works for older version also

Answer (score 1):

More information is required, what older versions are you using?

You can use the caniuse website to check browser compatibility with HTML and CSS features.

- `align-items` is not supported by Firefox version 19 nor previous versions.
- It also is not supported by Chrome version 20 nor previous versions.
- Chrome versions 51 - 21 required the prefix `-webkit-`.

Reference: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_align-items_flex_context

If you are using newer versions that those mentioned above I recommend you to mention with which element `align-items` is not working.

- If it is the label, it does not work because you are using `position: absolute`.